# Add Id to iframe tag with JS

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to add an ID to an iframe tag using Jquery.

Like this :

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

TO

```
<iframe id="something"></iframe>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Assuming there is only one iFrame on the page..would this work? `$("iframe").prop("id", "something");` ?

Comment: thanks a lot , yes i've only one iframe, but where should i write this code, in <script> tag ? Will it be executed after the iframe is loaded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You can use `attr()` method in jquery for iframe, see below code

NOTE : - Assuming you have only one iframe element, otherwise below code will set id of every iframe in html DOM

You need to add jquery library (jquery.min.js as shown below ) and put your script inside `script` tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
    $('iframe').attr('id','something');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot , yes i've only one iframe, but where should i write this code, in <script> tag ? Will it be executed after the iframe is loaded ?

Comment: also please...would you know how to add a param to a youtube src ? <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vfffv2VDvY0?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0"> TO <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vfffv2VDvY0?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1">

Comment: you can read value using `attr('src')` and then append your param and set it again.